# How to efficiently find nth element in a tfrecord dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator, dataset

Given a dataset object of `tf.data.TFRecordDataset()`,
what is the most efficient way to access the nth element in the dataset object?

My current method is to `iter()` on dataset `ds` which is very inefficient when I want to find the 2000th or the 3000th element:

```
iterator = iter(ds)
for i in range(0,idx):
    iterator.get_next()
window = iterator.get_next()
```

Is there better ways to quickly access an element of a specific index?

Comment: Can you use itertools.islice and convert your iterator to a new iterator

Comment: One way would be to use `take` and `skip` if your dataset is not yet batched / shuffled.

Comment: @AloneTogether Well unfortunately this operation happens after batching and shuffling

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the whole thing in memory, there are no advantages of keep dealing with iterators - just create a list with all elements and use normal indexed access to your elements:

```
data = list(ds)
```

(I don't know the exact API of TFReecordDataSets - just in case they error being passed to a `list()`, do it with an iter - `data = list(iter(ds))` )

From this point on you have random access for free to any record.